# Can application on computer communicate with other application on same computer using TCP?

Tags: tcp

one application on a computer can talk to another application on the same computer using TCP? Explain

Comment: Just to expand on Teun's answer. Imagine running a service and a client on the same machine. For example FTP server and a FTP client. You can then use the local address such as 127.0.0.1 and establish a TCP connection. The same mechanism would be employed whether it a remote server or a local server.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as long as there are no firewall policies to prevent this there's nothing special about that.